# Uninstall expo sdk and setup firebase instead

Tags: react-native, expo

We developed a React Native application with Expo Kit SDK. Now, We would change the native full Firebase SDK, but before we have to uninstall Expo SDK (Expo doesn't support external native sdk services). Is there a best practice to do that as easy as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I believe for Expo it's called detaching, like CRNA is ejecting...
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach

```
1. Install exp
```

If you don't have it, run npm install -g exp to get our command line library.
If you haven't used exp or XDE before, the first thing you'll need to do is log in with your Expo account using exp login.

```
2. Make sure you have the necessary keys in app.json
```

Detaching requires the same keys as building a standalone app. Follow these instructions before continuing to the next step.

```
3. Detach
```

From your project directory, run exp detach. This will download the required dependencies and build native projects under the ios and android directories.

```
4. Set up and Run your native project
```

Congrats, you now have a native project with ExpoKit! Follow the directions under Developing with ExpoKit to get things set up and running.

```
5. Make native changes
```

You can do whatever you want in the Xcode and Android Studio projects.
To add third-party native modules for React Native, non-Expo-specific instructions such as react-native link should be supported. Read more details about changing native dependencies in your ExpoKit project.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer seems logical.